# Settings - Drupal Integration Not Listing Tables

Tags: drupal

When I go to the *Settings - Drupal Integration* page I do not see the print out of the array that needs to be added to settings.php. I know this was here before.

[image]

I have cleared the CiviCRM cache and the Drupal cache.

I am running CiviCRM 4.6.24.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the Views module enabled?  I encountered this once and I think it was just that Views was not installed/enabled.